# Sharing custom config section across multiple systems

Tags: .net, handler, config

I have multiple projects like WEB / EXEs / WCF services / windows services in my solution and all these systems are referring to custom configuration section settings as mentioned below. At present, I have copied this custom config section to each and every web.config / exe.config files and I feel, with this approach, I will have to modify and edit the corresponding web.config / exe.config files whenever there is any modification is done to my custom config section. I feel, this approach is going to be cumbersome and difficult to manage going forward.  Is there any better approach for handling this scenario so that I need to maintain custom config section in a separate config file and I need to refer this config file (and read corresponding settings from config section) in each and every project config file? Kindly let me know your valuable tips.

Custom config section:

```
  
  <configSections>
    <section name="CustomConfigSection" type="Company.Product.ConfigSettings.CustomConfigSection, Company.Product.ConfigSettings" />
  </configSections>

  <CustomConfigSection>
     other relevant settings 
  </CustomConfigSection>
```

Answer (score 2):

Does storing the custom config in an external file help?

http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/16/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could store settings in the registry as an alternative option.